# Amount of facebook likes for external content like picture gallery on independent website

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like, external

I'm currently in the progress of understanding how the "like" system for external content works, read a lot of stuff, but finally there are some missing bricks in the wall I try to construct...

Background: We (me and some other people) have a own homepage with pictures shot at parties, public events and so on. Pictures taken with consent of depicted persons, those will look at those pics the day after and download them, put them into social media and like them on facebook.
We have a facebook page where we can announce some stuff concerning our homepage, so we can also use facebook statistics and have a connection to facebook users.

As I am currently in the progress to reorganize logfile processing/statistics (I do not program the site, this is done by my buddies) I want to also know, how many facebook likes one particular picture (or gallery) got.
We already use the fbxml system.
Content ist organized in picture galleries, where there is a single gallery per event with a unique id. 
Something like:
http://partypics.example.com/index.php?content=foo&show=gallery&galleryid=12345
Pictures get also referred by their ID.

Liking pictures already works fine.

I now want to go through the galleries and find out how many "likes" any picture has really gotten- I know that you could use something like "edge.create" to do some entry into a log, but this as far as I am aware does not cover likes done by different folks via facebook itself (or sharing etc.)

Question: Is there any way that this picture (or the gallery) has an unique facebook ID, which I can query via Opengraph via http or on commandline with FQL statements?
If, how do I find out the ID of that? (Or is it possible to set it via meta tags?

Will be thankful for any input to some documentation covering that...

Comment: Your idea is amazing but you maybe left with just subscribing to edge.create option as everything on Facebook get a unique id, so if anyone downloads image from your site, uploads and gets like then that will be on entirely different id as compared to the original image even if their properties are also same.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is there any way that this picture (or the gallery) has an unique facebook ID, which I can query via Opengraph via http or on commandline with FQL statements? If, how do I find out the ID of that?

For Open Graph Objects their URL *is* their “id” in the Graph.

For example, `http://example.com/` has been shared and commented on quite a bit – how much exactly, you can see by visiting http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com/

So, set up your galleries and your pictures as Open Graph objects, providing all the relevant meta tags – and afterwards you’ll be able to query the likes from the API via their OG URL.

(I’d recommend setting your pictures up as full OG objects as well, meaning creating a page with OG meta tags for each one of them, and have users like that page instead of just the picture URL – otherwise you will not be able to supply OG information, because a picture URL alone does not let you place meta information anywhere.)